# Trolls pretending to be Knights and Knaves

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

There are two Trolls, and each makes a statement.

Troll 1 says "if we are cousins, then we are both knaves."

Troll 2 says "we are cousins, or we are both knaves."

- Could both of the trolls be knights?
- How would a truth table for this problem be constructed?

Answer (score 3):

Answer:

> They cannot be both Knights.

Reasoning:

If I say according to [troll], I mean the logical information gathered given that they are a Knight or Knave.

Case 1: Knight & Knight

> That means that in the case that they are cousins, they would be Knaves. This means they are not cousins. Also, according to Troll2, we know that either they are cousins, are both Knaves, or both. They are not cousins, and they are not both Knaves. Thus a contradiction.

Case 2: Knave & Knave

> Troll2 explicitly states: "We are cousins OR We are both Knaves". If either statement holds true, then he is telling a true statement that he should not be telling. They are both Knaves, so his entire statement is true. But he is a Knave, so that can't be true! Contradiction.

Case 3: Knight & Knave

> According to Troll1, if they are cousins, they would be both Knaves. They clearly cannot be cousins, then. According to Troll2, they are neither cousins, nor both Knaves. This works.

Case 4: Knave & Knight

> So if they are cousins, they are not both Knaves. According to Troll2, we know that either they are cousins, are both Knaves, or both. They are not both Knaves, so they must be cousins. If they are cousins, then they are apparently not both Knaves by Troll1. This works.

So,

> If Troll1 is a Knave, Troll2 is a Knight.
> If Troll1 is a Knight, Troll2 is a Knave.

I really hope I didn't slip up...

Comment: The Question is : Could both of the trolls be knights?, so your answer must be No

Comment: Aight, fixed. [FILLER TEXT BECAUSE 15 CHARACTERS]

Comment: @greenturtle3141: Gosh, if you had just said "All right, fixed." you would have had 17.

Comment: Only "Case 1: Knight & Knight" needed to be examined . There was no need to examine the other possibilities , in my opinion .

Comment: Sure, but it doesn't hurt to determine all possibilities for the sake of it, since there are 4.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

> One troll is a knight, the other a knave. So no, they cannot be both knights.

Reasoning:

> If Troll 1 is a knight, then either they are cousins AND both are knaves, OR they are not cousins. The first is clearly a contradiction, therefore they are not cousins. Since they are not cousins, Troll 2 cannot be a knight, because then he would be lying. So Troll 2 is a knave, and this works. If on the other hand Troll 1 is a knave, then it must be the case that they are cousins AND they are not both knaves, hence Troll 2 is a knight. And his statement is true (since they are cousins), so this works too.

Concerning the truth table:

> Assuming that a troll is either a knight or a knave, you need a 2x2 matrix to record the possibilities. Then, both trolls are either cousins or they are not; it is impossible that only one is a cousin (being cousins is not a property of one troll). This can be represented by adding a layer, where one 2x2 layer represents the trolls being cousins, and the second represents the trolls not being cousins. This gives a 2x2x2 cube of truth values.

Answer (score -1):

Although if this is the intended answer, I would expect a lateral tag:

> Both can be knights since that the "we" the trolls speak of is the same group is an assumption.
>  e.g.:
>  Troll 2 looks at it's cousin Troll 1 and says truthfully: "we are cousins, or we are both knaves."  Two headed Troll 1 says truthfully to their other head: "if we are cousins, then we are both knaves.".
>
>  The truth-table then would have 16 entries with: Troll-1=knight/knave Troll-2=knight/knave, Troll-1's "we" revers to cousins, Troll-2's "we" revers to cousins. This has (knight,knight,no,yes) as a valid result.

Answer (score -4):

Your truth table needs 6 columns. Each troll might be a knave, might be a knight, and might be a cousin. Each is either true or false. That makes 2^6 = 64 possibilities.

First enumerase all the possibilities. Then, row by row, remove impossible combinations. (E.g. it is not possible for one to be a cousin, and the other not)

Trolls: before you down vote,  ***please*** put a little effort in to learn some mathematics - this is what the OP asked for; not an answer on a plate, but a means of solving such puzzles

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you probably want to show your idea more visually(though I understand if it's hard to format) and also explain your thought process.

Comment: Each one might be a cousin (either true or false)?  So Troll 1 might be a cousin and Troll 2 might not be a cousin?  Think about what "we are cousins" *means*.

Comment: @PeregrineRook truth table rows are eliminated until the final answer remains. Including requiring both to be cousins, or both not. He asked for a truth table, and that's how truth tables work.

Comment: @Jodes that's not right... there are only three (or two) input variables to consider, Are the trolls cousins, and are both trolls knaves. From that you con compare the truth values of their statements to get greenturtle's answer

Comment: @sconibulus both would work, I would use my method as it makes the eliminations more explicit